# how to use fckeditor in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, fckeditor, rich-text-editor, grails-2.0

I did the install:

> grails install-plugin fck-editor

i added to config:

```
fckeditor {
    upload {
        basedir = "/tmp/storagearea/"
        baseurl = "/uploads/"
        overwrite = false
        link {
            browser = true
            upload = false
            allowed = []
            denied = ['html', 'htm', 'php', 'php2', 'php3', 'php4', 'php5',
                      'phtml', 'pwml', 'inc', 'asp', 'aspx', 'ascx', 'jsp',
                      'cfm', 'cfc', 'pl', 'bat', 'exe', 'com', 'dll', 'vbs', 'js', 'reg',
                      'cgi', 'htaccess', 'asis', 'sh', 'shtml', 'shtm', 'phtm']
        }
        image {
            browser = true
            upload = true
            allowed = ['jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png']
            denied = []
        }
        flash {
            browser = false
            upload = false
            allowed = ['swf']
            denied = []
        }
        media {
            browser = false
            upload = false
            allowed = ['mpg','mpeg','avi','wmv','asf','mov']
            denied = []
        }
    }
}
```

Paste

```
 <fck:editor width="600" height="400">HELLO</fck:editor>
```

in my edit.gsp

The edit does not show in the browser.

full doc: http://grails.org/plugin/fckeditor
running ubuntu 10.04 LTS and grails 2.0.3

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of Grails are you running?

Comment: fck edtior is a really getting old, we are using ckeditor without problems. http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 1):

The FCKEditor plugin is a very old plugin that hasn't been updated in two years. You should be using the [CKEditor plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/ckeditor) that tracks the latest version of FCKEditor, now called [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

The correct tag that you need to embed the editor is `<ckeditor:editor>`. You will need to include the `<ckeditor:resources />` in the `<head>` in order  to include the Javascript and other static files needed to instantiate the editor.